# Save the page as HTML file including the newly added elements via JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web application that adds an HTML element (like div) using JavaScript via `appendChild()` function. When I inspect (after adding div) with Firebug, it shows the newly added div. But when I see the source code in the browser, it does not reflect the changes.

My question is: How to save the newly added div, along with other HTML elements, as an HTML file using either JavaScript or jQuery?

---

Source Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page title</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnAddtoList').click(function(){
    if( $('#inputAddtoList').val() == '' ) {alert("please enter some value."); }
    var text = $('#inputAddtoList').val();
    var newDiv = $('<div class="listing"><h4>' + text + '</h4></div>');
    $('body').append(newDiv);
    $('#inputAddtoList').val('');
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter Question: <BR/><textarea id="inputAddtoList" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Enter Question Here..." autofocus></textarea> 
<button id="btnAddtoList">Add Question</button>
 <BR /><BR />
<strong>Question :</strong>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by saving html page?

Comment: @jonju I mean automating the functionality similar to File-> Save (or Save As)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source code is what the server sent to the browser, it can't reflect the live changes. `Firebug` helps you to inspect live DOM. By using jQuery you can get the HTML of any element in your page including the whole page `$("html").html()`. Modern browsers support saving files by using HTML5 W3C saveAs() function and the [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) as polyfill:

```
var blob = new Blob([$("html").html()], {type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "page.html");
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/iRbouh/dj5j3kLd/

Comment: One of us didn't get this question, but now we must learn which one? :D

Comment: @jazzgot I believe that the OP question is: how to save the newly added div, along with other HTML elements, as an **HTML page**  using either **JavaScript** or **jQuery** ? You decide :D

Comment: I understand HTML page as page which you can display from every browser on machine connected to Internet and you understand it as a file which you can run locally.

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH Thanks for the answer. It really worked.

Comment: @jazzgot Okey, I see now what you understood ! I think the misleading sentence here is **source code of the page** but server/client side! you must extract that from the context !

Answer (score 0):

When you add an element to the DOM with JavaScript, you can't show it directly on the source code, because it is added dynamically. But you can inspect it (right click on the page), and show how DOM element are created by JavaScript.

Comment: I have updated my question and added code for your information.

Answer (score -1):

You actually want to change your HTML file but **it is impossible to do that without any server-side programming.** You can't modify actual files on server using only client-side JavaScript.

Only way to do that using JavaScript is server-side script running on Node.js and communicating with your client-side code.

Comment: Can I use AJAX to achieve my goal?

Comment: Sure, but still you need some server-side code which recive your AJAX "message". For example you can use simple PHP script.

Comment: @Asad Do you want to save this file on your computer or you want to changes be visible on your website?

Comment: @jazzgot I want to save html file on my local computer, not on website or internet.

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstand you, in this case @IsmailRBOUH give you a good answer. Can you try do make your question clear for future readers? :)