# How do I permanently add a item to a list in a HTML file using that file

Tags: html

I am wondering how I can add an item to a list using a JS form. 
Currently, I am trying to use a form to add an item to my list. I have seen other examples where this task is accomplished but when you refresh the page the previously inputted data goes away. How do I make the inputted data save on the HTML file? Below is my form:

```
<form name="Add-item">
    Choose a list: <select name="LIST">
        <option value="Helpfull links">Helpfull links</option>
        <option value="Favorits">Favorits</option>
        <option value="Single">Single</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Title: <input type="text" name="TITLE">
    <br><br>
    Link: <input type="text" name="LINK">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="additem()" value="Add item">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save the page as HTML file including the newly added elements via JavaScript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688568/save-the-page-as-html-file-including-the-newly-added-elements-via-javascript-jqu)

Comment: You need store and retrieve data from [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), even you refresh the page the data stays until you clear it

Comment: @SameerKhan Will this save the file or just keep it the browser's memory?

Comment: @Calvin this will store only in the browser's memory, but until you clear it. BTW you can't read file system with any front-end framework